# CrossEntropyLoss equivalence to LogSoftmax + NLLLoss

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

According to the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html), `CrossEntropyLoss` criterion combines `LogSoftmax` function and `NLLLoss` criterion.

That is all fine and well, but testing it doesn't seem to substantiate this claim (ie assertion fails):

```py
model_nll = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(3072, 1024),
                          nn.Tanh(),
                          nn.Linear(1024, 512),
                          nn.Tanh(),
                          nn.Linear(512, 128),
                          nn.Tanh(),
                          nn.Linear(128, 2),
                          nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1))


model_ce = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(3072, 1024),
                          nn.Tanh(),
                          nn.Linear(1024, 512),
                          nn.Tanh(),
                          nn.Linear(512, 128),
                          nn.Tanh(),
                          nn.Linear(128, 2),
                          nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1))

loss_fn_ce = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
loss_fn_nll = nn.NLLLoss()

t = torch.rand(1,3072)
target = torch.tensor([1])

with torch.no_grad():
    loss_nll = loss_fn_nll(model_nll(t), target)
    loss_ce = loss_fn_ce(model_ce(t), target)
    assert torch.eq(loss_nll, loss_ce)
```

I'm obviously missing something basic here.

Comment: I think weights from `model_nll` and `model_ce` have not been initialized. Then, they could be different...

Comment: @PatricioLoncomilla I believe you are right. I'm not sure how to get both networks to have exactly the same weights upon initialization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed, the weights are initialized randomly.

One way to get two modules sharing the same weights is to simply export with [`state_dict`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=state_dict#torch.nn.Module.state_dict) the state of one and set it on the other with [`load_state_dict`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=state_dict#torch.nn.Module.load_state_dict).

This is a one-liner:

```
>>> model_ce.load_state_dict(model_nll.state_dict())
```

Comment: Verfied this one liner and works thank you

Answer (score 0):

The following assertion passes:

```py
model = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(3072, 1024),
    nn.Tanh(),
    nn.Linear(1024, 512),
    nn.Tanh(),
    nn.Linear(512, 128),
    nn.Tanh(),
    nn.Linear(128, 2),
)


loss_fn_nll = nn.NLLLoss()
loss_fn_ce = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

t = torch.rand(1, 3072)
target = torch.tensor([1])

with torch.no_grad():

    loss_nll = loss_fn_nll(nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)(model(t)), target)
    loss_ce = loss_fn_ce(model(t), target)

    assert torch.eq(loss_nll, loss_ce)
```

I assume the weights are randomly generated in the two networks in the original question. Even with `torch.manual_seed(0)` it still doesn't equate.

Answer (score 0):

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
model_nll = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(3072, 1024),
                          nn.Tanh(),
                          nn.Linear(1024, 512),
                          nn.Tanh(),
                          nn.Linear(512, 128),
                          nn.Tanh(),
                          nn.Linear(128, 2),
                          nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1))


model_ce = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(3072, 1024),
                          nn.Tanh(),
                          nn.Linear(1024, 512),
                          nn.Tanh(),
                          nn.Linear(512, 128),
                          nn.Tanh(),
                          nn.Linear(128, 2)
)

model_nll.load_state_dict(dict(model_ce.named_parameters()))


loss_fn_ce = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
loss_fn_nll = nn.NLLLoss()

t = torch.rand(1,3072)
target = torch.tensor([1])

with torch.no_grad():
    loss_nll = loss_fn_nll(model_nll(t), target)
    loss_ce = loss_fn_ce(model_ce(t), target)

    print(loss_nll, loss_ce)
    assert torch.eq(loss_nll, loss_ce)
```

Your code has two problems:

- The weights must be identical in both models. Initialization is always random, therefore you must force them to be the same.
- You should not add the LogSoftmax in the model_ce, internally in the CrossEntropyLoss it is already computed. This allows it to be numerically more stable: it simplifies the derivative and allows the log-sum-exp trick to be applied.